# Is it possible to navigate into zip files with Ranger?

Tags: linux, zip, ranger

I'm starting to use Ranger file manager, but I'm missing a nice feature present in Total (and Double) Commander that I really like.

It is the possibility of navigating into zip files (and other kind of archives) as if they were normal folders, keeping the ability to copy, move, etc, into and out of the archive.

Is this (easily) achievable with Ranger?

Comment: The amount of guides/tutorials about dealing with compressed files in Ranger strongly suggests the feature you want is not available.

Comment: That's what I think, but maybe...

Comment: you can use vim to do what you want. So if you don't mind leaving ranger, get ranger to use vim to open the zip file.